# Getting a javascript variable out of a python selenium call

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am currently using Python with selenium to monitor changes to our pbx.  A value I need is being called by a javascript call and is not actually being written to html so it's been a little confusing as to how I can extract the value.  If I inspect the element this is what I see

```
<input class="SEditorInputText" id="extension_4" maxlength="15" onkeyup="javascript:onEditNumber(this);" onchange="javascript:onPropertyChange(this);" type="text">
```

On the web page it displays the number 1001 which is our huntgroup number.  I am assuming that number is generated by the **onkeyup="javascript:onEditNumber(this)** function, if so is there a way to get the output to console so that I may evaluate the number assigned?

Here's my selenium code thus far

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import sys, urllib2
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

login_username = '<username>'
login_password = '<password>'

url = '<login Url>'
scripts = '<scripts Url>'

driver.get(url)

username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

username.send_keys(login_username)
password.send_keys(login_password)

link = driver.find_element_by_name("loginbutton")
link.click()

driver.get(scripts)

aa = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[contains(@onclick, 'compsci-main-aa.aef')]").click()

opt1 = driver.find_element_by_id('extension_4')
```

It so far works as expected going to the section in question but like I mentioned before, I need the value of that variable.  When complete this script will be running headless.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I can think of two approaches for this.

1. If you know the name of the JavaScript function you want to execute, you can do something like:

   `num = driver.execute_script('return onEditNumber()')`
2. If you don't know the name of the JavaScript function but you know the element and the event that triggers it, you can do:

   `func_name = driver.find_element_by_id('extension_4').get_attribute('onkeyup')`

   `func_name = func_name[func_name.index(':')+1:] # this will strip off 'javascript:' from the string name, so now 'func_name' contains 'onEditNumber();'`

   `num = driver.execute_script('return ' + func_name)`

And if this JavaScript function returns a value, it will be stored in 'num'

Comment: Hmm, it is throwing this error when I try the second method.   ---- selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: curValue is undefined
Stacktrace:
    at SelectedCharsOnly (http://x.x.x.x/Web/Common/JS/functions.js:541)
    at NumericCharsOnly (http://x.x.x.x/Web/Common/JS/functions.js:570)
    at onEditNumber (http://x.x.x.x/Web/Common/JS/functions.js:766)
    at anonymous (http://x.x.x.x/Web/seditor/SEditor.do line 69 > Function:1)
    at handleEvaluateEvent (http://x.x.x.x/Web/seditor/SEditor.do:69)
----

Answer (score 3):

I have not tested it yet, but just read in another question in SO.

If you have a variable, say ,

```
var oneVariable = "A_String_Variable";
```

Then, you would want to create a method  calling and returning **window.oneVariable** in python using **driver.execute_script()**

I will update this post after attempting this logic and testing. Please check this answer to get an Idea.

[How to get the localStorage with Python and Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361494/how-to-get-the-localstorage-with-python-and-selenium-webdriver/46361900)

```
**-------------------------------**
```

So my tested and working code is-
i have this variable in javasript-
`var na ;`
I am getting it on selenium like this -

```
newav = r"file:///C://Users\\admin\\Desktop\\teast elete.html"
driver.get(newav)
sleep(15)
namee = driver.find_element_by_id("name").text
print(namee)
body = driver.find_element_by_id("body").get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(body)
bnb = driver.execute_script("""return window.na""")
print("bnb")
print(bnb)
bnb = driver.execute_script("""return na""")
print("bnb")
print(bnb)
```