# How to get the localStorage with Python and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, local-storage, selenium-chromedriver

What's the equivalent of:

`driver.get_cookies()`

to get the LocalStorage instead of Сookies?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I solved using:

`driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage;")`

EDIT: this is a quick and short answer. See Florent B.'s answer for a more detailed one.

Answer (score 89):

The python API doesn't provide a way to directly read/write the local storage, but it can be done with `execute_script`.

```
class LocalStorage:

    def __init__(self, driver) :
        self.driver = driver

    def __len__(self):
        return self.driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage.length;")

    def items(self) :
        return self.driver.execute_script( \
            "var ls = window.localStorage, items = {}; " \
            "for (var i = 0, k; i < ls.length; ++i) " \
            "  items[k = ls.key(i)] = ls.getItem(k); " \
            "return items; ")

    def keys(self) :
        return self.driver.execute_script( \
            "var ls = window.localStorage, keys = []; " \
            "for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; ++i) " \
            "  keys[i] = ls.key(i); " \
            "return keys; ")

    def get(self, key):
        return self.driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage.getItem(arguments[0]);", key)

    def set(self, key, value):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.setItem(arguments[0], arguments[1]);", key, value)

    def has(self, key):
        return key in self.keys()

    def remove(self, key):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.removeItem(arguments[0]);", key)

    def clear(self):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.clear();")

    def __getitem__(self, key) :
        value = self.get(key)
        if value is None :
          raise KeyError(key)
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.set(key, value)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.keys()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.items().__iter__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.items().__str__()
```

Usage example:

```
# get the local storage
storage = LocalStorage(driver)

# set an item
storage["mykey"] = 1234
storage.set("mykey2", 5678)

# get an item
print(storage["mykey"])      # raises a KeyError if the key is missing
print(storage.get("mykey"))  # returns None if the key is missing

# delete an item
storage.remove("mykey")

# iterate items
for key, value in storage.items():
  print("%s: %s" % (key, value))

# delete items
storage.clear()
```

Comment: Can  saved values be accessed after closing and reopening the browser?

Comment: Probably not, as each new window is in Incognito mode.

Comment: cool implementation

Comment: I tried this solution on local storage having more than one items/entries by executing this command `print(storage.items())` but it gives me empty dict. Any solution??

Comment: Any idea how to make `storage.clear()` work in geckodriver without getting `JavascriptException: SecurityError: The operation is insecure`?

Answer (score 8):

See the answer to the question [Getting the return value of Javascript code in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585343/getting-the-return-value-of-javascript-code-in-selenium/5585345#5585345).

Basically, you need to do something like the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

wd = webdriver.Firefox()
wd.get("http://localhost/foo/bar")
wd.execute_script("return localStorage.getItem('foo')")
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.setItem('key','value');")
driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.getItem('key');")
```