# Selenium Local Storage Problem: Cannot read property

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

i am running into a error when executing my python script:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.discord.com/register")
time.sleep(3)
driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.getItem('fingerprint');")
```

I use Chrome version 90 and chromedriver version 90.
The error i get is:

*selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined*

SessionInfo:
(Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Can you please add more information what are you trying to achieve!

Comment: I am trying to access the local storage of the site by this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46361494/15959343
Btw the error appears on multiple solutions to access the local storage

Comment: Try `driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage.getItem('fingerprint');")` - adding a return before the actual js statement.

Comment: same error as before and as always -<-