# How to add localStorage with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I use this

```
driver=webdriver.Edge(executable_path="C:\webdriver\msedgedriver.exe")       
driver.add_cookie(i)
```

to add cookie but It have for localStorage?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the localStorage with Python and Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361494/how-to-get-the-localstorage-with-python-and-selenium-webdriver) See the first answer for  setting and getting localStorage values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361840/8375783