# How to get value from localstorage Chromedriver python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am always getting `None` result when I read value "token" from discord verification link. How can I get token value from localstorage for Chromedriver?

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
import time 

recreate_localStorage_script = '''
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.head.append(iframe);
    const pd = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(iframe.contentWindow, 'localStorage');
    iframe.remove();    
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', pd);
    '''

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = "C:\\Users\\nicvaldy\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 38"
options.add_argument(f"user-data=dir={profile}",)
mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile Safari/535.19" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,use_subprocess=True)
driver.get("https://click.discord.com/ls/click?")
driver.execute_script(recreate_localStorage_script)  # Recreating the localStorage Object again, has to be done after every reload
print('token:', driver.execute_script(
    f"return window.localStorage.getItem('token');"))

time.sleep(160)
```

**Check key and values**

[image: token]

**Result**

[image: result]

Comment: Hi ! Have you you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361494/how-to-get-the-localstorage-with-python-and-selenium-webdriver ?

Comment: yes, it doesnt work