# Staying logged in Instagram with Selenium [Python]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm making a bot that scrapes ig. The problem is that my accounts/ip already got flagged, just by building & testing the bot. So I need to keep sessions alive.

I tried using pickle: login, save the cookies and load the previously saved cookies at the next log in. It did nothing, except getting rid of the cookiewall. Login was still required.
Any cookies save/load that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple factors which might need to be consistent:

1. **IP** (use same IP for one Account)
2. **Cookies**, as you allready mentioned
3. **Local Storage** (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361900/20443541) for implementation with Python
4. **Browser-Fingerprint** This might be possible to resolve using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles)

Disclosure: I am the Author of [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles)