# Selenium Python - extract Javascript as string

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can I extract JavaScript code using Python Selenium, In other words, i need the js code as string

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Password"].value;
  if (x.length >= 6) {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Where that function declaration is located? Show your code

Comment: form onsubmit="validateForm()"

Comment: @JaSON I don't have source code for the web application because I work on implementing crawling to analyze JS code. So I need the JS code as a string to extract specific information. I need the steps to do that.

Comment: Does it help in any way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948978/7610724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use BeautifulSoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
script_code = soup.find('script')
```